# Error en un método en python

Tags: python

Estoy empezando a ver clases, métodos y atributos.

Tengo este código, que debe obtener el area del cuadrado, pero me aparece un error "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were  given". Me podrían ayudar? Ya intente cambiando el nombre de "lado" por "side_length", pero me sigue apareciendo el error. Muchas gracias!

```
class Square():
    def area(lado):
        resultado = (lado*2)
        return resultado
        

figure = Square()
side_length = int(input("Ingresa la longitud del lado del cuadrado: "))
print(figure.area(side_length))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los métodos de una clase deben tener `self` por primer parámetro:

```
class Square():
    def area(self, lado):
        resultado = (lado * 2)
        return resultado


figure = Square()
side_length = int(input("Ingresa la longitud del lado del cuadrado: "))
print(figure.area(side_length))
```

`self` es una referencia al objeto en particular, y sirve para recuperar los atributos propios de la instancia.

Comment: muchas gracias!, se me habia pasado ese detalle :)